# Android animation moves the Layout, but not the buttons

Tags: android

Say I have a "main screen" Layout which has to move up, to reveal a "history bar".

```
if ( HistoryBar == false )
                    {
                        HistoryBar = true;
                        TranslateAnimation MainScreenPullUp = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -200 );
                        MainScreenPullUp.setDuration(350);
                        MainScreenPullUp.setFillAfter(true);
                        LinLayMain.startAnimation(MainScreenPullUp);
                    }
```

Right now I am doing it like that. But the problem is, that while the main screen layout itself moves up, all the button places keep the same, i.e. the button picture moves, but the click-spot remains in place. Any ideas how to fix that?

I tried useing an animationListener, instead setFillAfter(true) , which would TanslateY the main screen layout, once the animation stops, but it makes the layout jump and flicker. Are there any other ways?

edit:

Thanks, Vineet.

Got it working with:

```
ObjectAnimator pullUp = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(LinLayMain, "translationY", 0f, -200f);
                        pullUp.setDuration(350);
                        pullUp.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. From 3.0 android has `property animation`. Below 3.0 I tackled this issue with the help of view's method `offsetLeftAndRight (int offset)` and `offsetTopAndBottom (int offset)`. You can refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#offsetLeftAndRight%28int%29) for more details.

For `Property animation` refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using 3+, so guess the property animation should help!

Comment: If I'm right, I should use the ValueAnimator on the TranslateY property?